# Pass JavaScript variable in URL in Rails 4 application so I can use it in controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pass value of a JavaScript variable in the URL and then
use that value in my Rails 4 app controller by accessing it through
`param[:my_variable]`. I have tried various methods suggested here but nothing worked for me, I am unable to pass my JavaScript variable to the URL and access it in the controller. I am new to Rails.

It would be a great help if you can suggest me a workaround, I am providing code which I have tried and it made sense to me as as well but it did not work:

```
<script>
    var content = 'something'; 
var url = '/index/view? 
message='+encodeURIComponent(content); 
new Ajax.Request(url, 
{ asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get', 
onComplete: function(t) { // do something
    alert('done'); 
 } 
});
</script>
```

Comment: did your ajax request is send to the server? check your browser console. It may be wrong ajax url.

Comment: it says " Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" which is var url= '/index/view?view'    i don't get it what is the error exactly

Comment: How does the code in line 47 and the context around look like? Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @aashi0001 what are you trying to accomplish with this js? Also the reason you are getting invalid token is because it expects a token in the header from your application to authenticate the data being passed in is not from someone who is maliciously trying to do some cross scripting.

Comment: [IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/2zprzt5.png[/IMG]          please see this picture for stacktarce @spickermann

Comment: @tall-paul  i want to pass my javascript variable in url so that i can access it in my rails 4 application controller

Comment: @aashi0001 sorry I am on a work computer and get blocked from seeing the stacktrace. I mean what on the page are you trying to accomplish as a user that you need js to gather data?

Comment: Your example has a new line in the url, is that your an error in the formatting on this site? If not, remove that new line.

Comment: Can you put the rails url you are trying eg:- `users_url`

Comment: @tall-paul  user is provided with a keypad like ios and when the user clicks on a number lets 4 then the users in his contact list with 4 in number and (G,H,I) in their name are display and i have to implement in rails web app so what i am doing is passing the whole data that is number 4 and GHI alphabets in an object as a string running a query "where {name} and {number} like" and fetching the results.

Comment: @spickermann : now its giving an error that "uncaught reference error ajax is not defined"

Comment: @abhi localhost:3000/index/view is the url

Comment: @aashi0001 My understanding is you have a list of contact and want to search based on the values selected? something like [this](http://mir.aculo.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Image2.png). If that is it then why not create a form that they can submit via rail's built in ajax handling? it is pretty easy / convenient

Comment: @tall-paul actually they want that trigger an  action with a key press and simultaneously fetch results if i build a from how will i get the number and the subscript text result with just key press ; i have never used from in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements of being able to search as a user inputs information I would recommend using a js library. These js libraries probably have a gem that someone has created that will help you run through searching this way.

These two videos are pretty good as showing live searching

- [Video 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?autoplay=true)
- [Video 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?autoplay=true)

Comment: thanks for answer buts please for now can you help me with passing JavaScript variable to rails controller , I really need help !

Answer (score 0):

the proper ajax syntax is

```
var url = '/index/view?' 
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'get',
      data: {your_js_variable: value},
      success:function(data){
          if(data.status == 'true'){
             // do as you like
          }
          else{
              // do as you like
          }
      }
  });
```

Then in your controller you can get the params like `params[:your_js_variable]`.

I skipped script tag.

hope that helps.